# Select child nodes until attribute value in xpath (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, xpath, xml-column

I have an XML column in SQL Server database (SQL Server 2012) with the following structure:

```
<history>
    <status updatedAt="2013-11-30" active="true" />
    <status updatedAt="2013-11-15" active="false" />
    <status updatedAt="2012-05-10" active="true" />
    <status updatedAt="2012-01-30" active="true" />
</history>
```

Newer statuses are added to the column as top nodes.

I need to select a subset of `<status>` nodes which includes first node which has `updatedAt` attribute less then or equal to given date AND all preceding nodes (or, all `<status`> nodes until `updatedAt` attribute is less then or equal to the given date).

How can I achieve this using XPath?

```
DECLARE @date DATE = '2012-30-10';
SELECT Statuses = Statuses.query('what should be there?')
```

For now I ended up with this query:

```
SELECT Statuses = Statuses.query'((/history/pricing[@updatedAt <= sql:variable("@date")])[1])')
```

but it returns the first node only, how can I include all its preceding siblings too?

Comment: Since you have American style dates it would suffice to compare the dates as strings. However, string comparison (<, >) is not available in XPath 1.0 which would require you to break down the string dates into their components. Hence the question: are you allowed to use XPath 2.0?

Comment: See solution #3 & #4.

Comment: My XML column is strongly typed, and **updatedAt** attribute is of type **xs:date** according to the schema. SQL Server compares it correctly with an SQL variable of type DATE. Please, see my update. Sql Server supports XPath 2.0, according to MSDN.

Comment: SQL Server implements large parts of XQuery 1.0 which includes XPath 2.0.

Comment: @nativehr: If you remove `[1]` from the last XQuery then you should receive all nodes not just first node.

Comment: Bogdan, thanks for your reply. I don't need all nodes, just first matched and all its preceding siblings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fetching all preceding siblings, use the `preceding-siblings` axis and select all siblings before *the last* matching `<pricing/>` tag.

```
SELECT Statuses = Statuses.query('
  /history/pricing[
      @updatedAt <= sql:variable("@date") and last()
  ]/preceding-sibling::pricing')
```

By the way, while your example data has `<status/>` tags, your query expects `<pricing/>` tags?

---

I forgot MS SQL Server doesn't support that axis, but it supports the node order operator `<<` which you can use to work around that. This query says "select all pricing nodes which occur before the last pricing node with this value".

```
/history/pricing[. << (/history/pricing[@updatedAt <= "2012-30-10"])[last()]]
```

Have a try on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/12422/0).

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support `preceding-sibling` axis. Thanks for your answer, anyway!

Comment: My bad, not the first time I trapped into that. I hope I will be able to remember that _at some time in future_... But it's not a real problem, added a workaround including SQL fiddle for testing.

Comment: Jens, it was just a typo, there should be `status` tags instead of `pricing` of course. Your last example is what I was looking for, thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome. SQL Server's lack of some XQuery capabilities is horrible, and I still haven't found a complete list of them. Another missing feature would be that you cannot use variables in element constructors' name fields.